# My logo is blurry on the navbar, looks small on desktop view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap on my website and have uploaded a high resolution version of my logo. The logo size is 529 x 100 pixels and this is what's in my CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 62px;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: Your logo won't reach its full size, because you have a `max-width: 200px` on its parent element `.navbar-brand`. You may want to experiment with the height you're setting on `.navbar-brand` as well, try making it atleast the height of your image

Comment: I have tried increasing the max-width but that messed up the nav menu when viewing the site on an iPad, logo was too big for it all to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem that usually causes it is the padding. I tried to move the padding to the `.navbar` class and it works now. Try to remove the padding and see if that works. If yes, then try to find a better place (outer container maybe?) to place the padding or perhaps margin.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is quite an old thread, but wanted to answer anyway. I was facing the same issue using Bootstrap 5.1.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="/docs/5.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I just needed to adjust the ratio of my logo and modify from the default Bootstrap setup. I modified it to width="117" height="21"